# How to fix " AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' " while replacing and writing to a new file?

Tags: python

**I have a `hello.py` file which asks user for their name and prints them a welcome message.**

```
import subprocess

filename = "hello-name.txt"

fout = open("out.txt", "w")

with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

your_name = input("What is your name? ")
title_name = your_name.title()

for line in lines:
    line = fout.write(line.replace("[Name]", your_name))
    line = fout.write(line.replace("[Title]", title_name))
    print(line.strip())

    subprocess.call(["notepad.exe", "out.txt"])
```

**This is the content of my `hello-name.txt` file**

```
Hello [Name]
Welcome to the world [Title]
```

**My Question**

When run `hello.py` it asks user for their Name and as soon as the name is entered, Python gives the **following error** :

```
line = fout.write(line.replace("[Title]", title_name))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this script:

1. As ShadowRanger pointed out, you're assigning the result from `write` to `line`; this overwrites the content.
2. You don't `close` the output file before opening it in Notepad.

An easy way to make sure a file is closed is to open it in a context, using the `with` keyword.  You already did this when you read the input file; just do the same thing for the output file, and open Notepad after the `with` block (i.e. after you've written both lines and closed the file):

```
import subprocess

with open("hello-name.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

your_name = input("What is your name? ")
title_name = your_name.title()

with open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace("[Name]", your_name)
        line = line.replace("[Title]", title_name)
        fout.write(line)
        print(line.strip())

subprocess.call(["notepad.exe", "out.txt"])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `write` method returns the number of characters written, not the value written. Don't assign the result to `line` if you want to keep using it. If the goal is to perform both replacements before writing, do them both, *then* write, e.g.:

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("[Name]", your_name)
    line = line.replace("[Title]", title_name)
    fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank You. I don't get any error but now why "out.txt" is empty instead of containing the message?

Comment: You failed to `flush` or `close` the file, so your data is stuck in user-mode buffers. Either `close` it, or if you need to keep it open for future appends, call `fout.flush()` so the user mode buffers are sent to the kernel to *actually* write the data to disk. This is the general rule with any file that you pass to some other API (or process) by name; user-mode buffered data is only visible on the handle it was written to until it is `flush`ed or `close`d.

Comment: I closed it by with "fout.close()". Just one more question. The "out.txt" file now contains just one message. It was not able to load the message of second line "Welcome to the world [Title]".

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be invoking `notepad` (or closing the file) until the loop is complete. Dedent the `subprocess` invocation.

Comment: Thank You for the help

Comment: I leaned that ".write" method is used to write to a file. What is the meaning of "The write method returns the number of characters written, not the value written."?

Comment: In some cases (e.g. non-blocking I/O), `write` isn't guaranteed to successfully write everything you asked it to write; it returns the number of characters it *did* write so you'd know how much got written, and how much is left over. It's not useful in most cases (e.g. in this case, writing to a buffered file where it's just going to tell you how much you passed it). It wouldn't make sense for it to return the data written in any event, so for your purposes, it's basically a garbage return value. You can see [the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write).

Comment: Thank You. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The return from fout.write is an integer.  Then you are trying to replace on an integer (it isn't giving you the replaced line.

Try:

```
import subprocess

filename = "hello-name.txt"

fout = open("out.txt", "w")

with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

your_name = input("What is your name? ")
title_name = your_name.title()

for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("[Name]", your_name)
    line = line.replace("[Title]", title_name)
    fout.write(line)
    print(line.strip())

fout.close()
subprocess.call(["notepad.exe", "out.txt"])
```

I changed it to a single fout since my guess is you don't want the double printing (but you can change it back).  You probably also want to make the notepad call after parsing everything (and closing the file as others have mentioned)